# how to make condition for image and message?

Tags: ios, iphone, image, null, facebook-sdk-4.0

in my project i get data from facebookSDK where I need to display images(if available), message(if available), numbers of likes, numbers of comments.

now in my data one image is there but message is not available. my string show me null message. now i need to put 3 conditions.

you can understand my question may be with below code.

```
        self.arrData = nil;
        self.arrData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        self.arrData = [result[@"data"] mutableCopy];

        for (int i =0; i<self.arrData.count; i++)
        {

        NSString *strImage1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[self.arrData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"full_picture"]];

        NSString *strComment =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[self.arrData objectAtIndex:i ]valueForKey:@"message"]];
//in strComment i get @"(null)" message.

        NSString *strLike = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[[[self.arrData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"likes"]valueForKey:@"summary"]valueForKey:@"total_count"]];
        NSString *strCommentCount = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[[[self.arrData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"comments"]valueForKey:@"summary"]valueForKey:@"total_count"]];

        NSString *strTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[self.arrData objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"created_time"]];


        CustomSocialView *imageView1 = [[CustomSocialView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, 170)];

        [self.vLayout addSubview:imageView1];


      //conditions      
            if (strImage1 == nil)// if image is not available.
            {
                NSLog(@"no image");
                [imageView1 setContentText:strComment like:strLike comment:strCommentCount time:strTime];
            }
            else if ([strCommentCount  isEqual: 0]) // if Message is not available // may be here i am wrong.
            {
                NSLog(@"no msg");
                [imageView1 setImage:strImage1 like:strLike comment:strCommentCount time:strTime];
            }
            else 
            {
                NSLog(@"Both image and msg are available");
                [imageView1 setImage:strImage1 setContentText:strComment like:strLike comment:strCommentCount time:strTime];
            }
```

now i am confused that how can i make condition for my code.

please help me for this.

Thank you.

Comment: you want to put your response data onto images or labels?

Comment: what it means  "isEqual: 0" you are passing a string value how could you compare a string value to integer value. try @"" instead of 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i<self.arrData.count; i++)
    {
       //your code

        if (strImage1 != nil && [strCommentCount intValue] != 0 )// if image is not available.
        {
            NSLog(@"Both image and msg are available");
            [imageView1 setImage:strImage1 setContentText:strComment like:strLike comment:strCommentCount time:strTime];
        }
        else
        {
            if ([strCommentCount intValue] != 0)
            {
                NSLog(@"no image");
                [imageView1 setContentText:strComment like:strLike comment:strCommentCount time:strTime];
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"no msg");
                [imageView1 setImage:strImage1 like:strLike comment:strCommentCount time:strTime];
            }
        }
    }
```